# How can we calculate the tensor product of Lagrange basis polynomials?

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, computational-mathematics, lagrange-interpolation

Given data points $(x_i,y_i)$, the *Lagrange basis polynomials* are $$\mathcal l_j(x):=\sum_{i\ne j}\frac{x-x_i}{x_j-x_i}\;.$$ I'm reading a text targeting *Smolyak's algorithm*. In this text, they use tensor products $$\mathcal l_{j_1}\otimes\mathcal l_{j_2}\otimes\mathcal l_{j_3}\cdots$$ of these basis polynomials. I need to explicitly calculate these tensor products. So, what exactly is $\mathcal l_{j_1}\otimes\mathcal l_{j_2}$?

Comment: That seem to be
$$
\ell_{j_1}(x) \ell_{j_2}(y)  \ell_{j_3}(z) \dots
$$
where $x, y, z, \dots$ are the point coordinates. I think tensor product is used to denote that each largange basis polynomial is applied to a single coordinate

Comment: @uranix I can confirm this. You should probably make this into an answer.